# asp.net login control

Tags: asp.net, authentication

im using asp.net for my webpage.  im also using the login control too.  i want it so when the user types in the correct user name and password, it redirects to a new page called test.aspx.  i dont want to use login view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.destinationpageurl.aspx
Alternatively you can hook to the login event and use Response.Redirect to redirect with C#/VB.NET code.

Answer (score 0):

But what actually is the problem here? You may want to build your own login mechanism. It may be as simple as placing two textboxes and a button on a page and then checking if the values provided are correct. To redirect the user to another page on successful login you may want to use:

```
Response.Redirect(url);
```

Be sure to check on the page that you are redirecting to that the user is authenticated and authorized to view this page (by using Session variables or whatever).